# which class cannot have an object other then pure virtual /abstract class?

Tags: c++

I have searched but could not find an answer.

My question is that we cannot make an object of an abstract class,

```
class Shape{
   public:
      virtual void area()=0;
       }


int main(){
    Shape obj // error
    }
```

how can i make simple/concrete class to give an error when its object is created without making it abstract ?

how can i make this concrete class to give me error when its object is created

```
 class Shape{
   public:
      void area(){}; //without making it pure virtual
       }

 int main(){
    Shape obj // when we create object, it should give error
    }
```

I m sure it can be done but i don't know how to do it.

Are there other classes that cannot have an object OR give an error when object is created?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have tagged it both `java` and `c++`, and your example is in C++. Are you looking for answers in both cases?

Comment: You have to inherit from the abstract class, to be able creating instances from the inherited classes.

Comment: You seem to want your second code to give a compile error, that is impossible. If it is a runtime error, then just throw an exception but I don't get the point of a concrete class which cannot be instantiated.

Comment: i want to ask that is there any other way to make a class object less means will give an error when its object its created like in case of abstract class, but without using a pure virtual function.

Comment: [I know this is long and all but here are some reading material for you :)](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

Comment: @Maaz: Care to explain what's so bad about virtual functions if you need some mechanism to choose concrete operations at run-time?

Comment: This looks like an interview question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to make the objects constructor protected. Like this

```
class Shape{
protected:
   Shape(){}//Only derived classes or friends can call this
public:
   void area(){}
};
class DShape:public Shape{
public:
   DShape(){}
};
int main(){
    Shape obj; // error: ‘Shape::Shape()’ is protected
    DShape obj2;//compiles fine
}
```

Comment: yes exactly that is the answer i m looking for. thank you for understanding my question and answer it.

Comment: It's stil possible to create an object of the class: You just need to do it from a derived classes (possibly static) member.

Comment: While this technically answsers the question, one has to wonder what the OP is up to here. What's the point of the inheritance relationship in the first place?

Comment: @Maaz And what will be the the effect of calling `area()` on a `Shape*` ?  Not having abstract ideas represented by abstract classes will backfire sooner or later...